# Android gmaps, .flat() and .rotate() methods not found

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I crated android applciation uses gmaps, so play lib version is:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}
```

And following code works perfect on most of my devices:

```
   markerOptions.position(latLng)
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .rotation(90)
```

But on one I have exception (Andrid 4.0.3) saing:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions.rotation

And when I check Goolge Play Services lib accroding to this http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

```
   int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
   if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        Log.i("GSR", "GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES VERSION IS AVAILABLE");
        return true;
   }
```

I do see SUCCESS message in logs.

So what we have: the lib version is obviusly not up to date, but it could not identify this.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I don't know how, but old version of google play services lib was packing in apk, what I did is start SDK manager, removed play services lib and goolge repository packages, and install them again. After that apk begin to work.